# child CSS style overwriting parent style when it should not

Tags: css, inheritance, browser

The below is a much simplified version of the real HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        h3 { background: blue; }
        p {background:grey; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>The paragraph below will style correctly.</h3>
    <p>
        As you can see, I am stylish.</p>
    <p>
        <h3>But this paragraph goes wrong.</h3>
        I am sad. I have no style.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Slap that in a browser (have tried Firefox 12 and IE9) and whilst the first paragraph gets a grey background, the second one has none. Note, it doesn't even have a blue background, the styling has been lost. It is my understanding that the background of the h3 should *only* affect the h3, not travel upward into the parent and affect that.

Have I missed something? Note the above is simplified. I want headers in my paragraphs, but this seems to be impossible without style errors. Is there a mistake in the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid markup to have headers within a paragraph which is why the styling is getting screwed up.

You can validate your markup here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks. I should have added that it is HTML5 for further detail. The validator returns the following error: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen. So looks like the presence of hX tag will close the scope of a P tag. I suppose semantically it makes a kind of sense. Thanks.